# PHP preg_replace with \s working different in windows

Tags: php, regex, windows

PHP 7.2.7 on Windows 10 (xampp)

```
$text = 'a  Ž b  c   d e';
```

Output working fine:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', TRUE);
```

Now I want replace spaces with a single underscore.

```
$text = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '_', $text);
```

Output with `echo $text` show me `a_�_b_c_d e`.
Output with `var_dump(htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', TRUE))` show now as result `string(0) ""`

Add modifier u to `preg_replace('/\s\s+/u', '_', $text)` the result is correct with `string(12) "a_Ž b_c_d e"`.

**In Linux its working without modifier u.**
https://regex101.com/r/sNIxdn/1/

When I use instead \s only a space: `preg_replace('/ +/', '_', $text)` its working too in Windows, without modifier u. But this replace all spaces, not only minimum two spaces.

What is the issue with preg_replace() and \s in Windows?

Comment: The pattern in your first two preg_replace are not equivalent.`[\s]+` is not equivalent to `\s\s+`.

Comment: What's the problem with the second pattern? It does what you want. See [here](https://ideone.com/4xnpvu).

Comment: I have rewritten the question, because I found this is a windows problem and not reproducible with linux.

Comment: The `u` flag stands for UTF-8 and it's basically mandatory. Otherwise you'll get matches on individual bytes, something that works (UTF-8 is a superset of US-ASCII) until it doesn't.

Comment: That not explain why in linux u modifier is not needed for this string and why without \s working fine.

Comment: @user706420 No idea about that. In fact, in my PC (official PHP/7.2.3 x64 binaries on Windows 10) it returns `string(12) "a_Ž b_c_d e"` in both cases.

Comment: @Alvaro With this preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '_', $text) without /u? Interessting, but what is on my php for windows different to yours?

Comment: Hard to say. Just tried with *PHP 7.2.6 (cli) (built: May 23 2018 20:29:41) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )* and same result.

Comment: I think the problem is that xampp for windows is 32Bit.